# Not refresh html properly when using duplicate component in angular 4 CLI

Tags: angular

i am having duplicate component present in html. When i do show delete first section will change and when i do show delete second section, first section block only got refreshed.

app.component.html:

```
<div fxLayout="row">
<mat-checkbox color="warn" [(ngModel)]="showDeleted1" (change)="showSample1()">
        <span class="helper-legend legend-red"></span>
        Show Deleted
      </mat-checkbox>
<sample-table [search]="sample1"></sample-table>
</div>
<div fxLayout="row">
<mat-checkbox color="warn" [(ngModel)]="showDelete2" (change)="showSample2()">
        <span class="helper-legend legend-red"></span>
        Show Deleted
      </mat-checkbox>
<sample-table [search]="sample2"></sample-table>
</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Sample } from '../../models/sample';
@Component({
  selector: 'demo',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  sample1: Sample = new Sample;
  sample2: Sample = new Sample;
  @ViewChild(SampleComponent) sampleComponent: SampleComponent;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  incShowdeletedChange() {
    this.sample1.deleteFlag = this.showDelete1 ? 1 : 0;
    this.sampleComponent.sample = this.sample1;
    this.sampleComponent.ngOnInit();
  }

  bookShowDeleteChange() {
    this.sample2.deleteFlag = this.showDelete2 ? 1 : 0;
    this.sampleComponent.search = this.sample2;
    this.sampleComponent.ngOnInit();
  }
}
```

sample.component.html:

```
<div>
    <p-table [value]="samples" #dt customSort="true">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Type
                </th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-sample let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
            <tr>
                <td>{{sample.date |date:'MM/dd/yy HH:mm'}}</td>
                <td>{{sample.type | slice: 0:50}}</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
</div>
```

sample.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Sample } from '../../models/sample';

@Component({
  selector: 'sample-table',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html'
})
export class AttachmentHistoryTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() sample = new Sample;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadgriddata();
  }

  loadgriddata() {
    this.service.getData(this.search).
      subscribe(res => {
        this.sample = res;
      },
      () => alert("error"));
  }
}
```

Each section will load different values, how can i achieve this scenaria. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be interesting to see your typescript code of the `showSample` functions, this doesn't necessarily need to be an html problem.

Comment: i have added my code, kindly have a look

Comment: `@ViewChild(SampleComponent) sampleComponent: SampleComponent;` you are referring here to only one of the two components, am I right? In your code later on you're calling functions only on this child, even though you want to update two different components. This way only the first component will be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're only referencing one SampleComponent, even though there are two in your view. Here's the problem.

```
@ViewChild(SampleComponent) sampleComponent: SampleComponent;
```

Later on you are referencing this component for both your html components, of course angular does not know which one you mean and therefore only updates one, the first on in this case.

In order to seperate between your two components in your `app.component.ts` you have to give the different components some angular identifiers. Here's an example for your case.

```
<sample-table #sampleTable1 [search]="sample1"></sample-table>
<sample-table #sampleTable2 [search]="sample2"></sample-table>
```

This way you can differentiate between both in your typescript file. Here are the `ViewChild` references for both.

```
@ViewChild("sampleTable1") sampleComponent1: SampleComponent;
@ViewChild("sampleTable2") sampleComponent2: SampleComponent;
```

We're now referencing each sample component on its own, then we can use that later on.

```
incShowdeletedChange() {
  this.sample1.deleteFlag = this.showDelete1 ? 1 : 0;
  this.sampleComponent1.sample = this.sample1;
  this.sampleComponent1.ngOnInit();
}

bookShowdeletedChange() {
  this.sample2.deleteFlag = this.showDelete2 ? 1 : 0;
  this.sampleComponent2.sample = this.sample2;
  this.sampleComponent2.ngOnInit();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your method. It helps to achieve my scenario.